# No result returned using Valence API desire2learn

Tags: desire2learn, valence

I'm working on migrating from SOAP to valence API. I'm having some problems with a few calls like getting users (All users, based on role, by userID, etc) and grades (All variations).

I see an empty list returned with no items. There's no error of any kind. When I try to get the data using SOAP, I get the desired data.

I've checked the permissions for "Search for Students", so technically, I should be getting something when I try to get all users or by role id of students. What else am I missing here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The D2LWS service's authentication mechanism puts the API caller in the position of being a privileged caller. The Valence Learning Framework APIs use a different auth model: the user ID/Key tokens that identify a user get employed by the back-end to restrict the functionality of calls. That is: the authenticated user should have access to the same functionality and data as the user would get through the web UI, and no more.

In this particular case, the calls succeed: they send back all the elements in the result set that your calling user has privileges to see -- none of them.

This is almost certainly an issue with the role privileges afforded to your calling user, and debugging the permissions around calls can be challenging. The Valence project's documentation provides a walkthrough topic on [investigating role permissions](http://docs.valence.desire2learn.com/samples/permissionCheck.html) that might shed let on a possible approach here, especially with respect to the calls to gain access to user records (or properties that appear in user records).

As the walkthrough discusses, there are various aspects to making the general call to `/d2l/api/lp/{version}/users/` that bring permissions into play:

- If you're trying to filter with a query parameter, does the calling user context have permissions to use the data on which you want to filter
- Does the calling user context have permission to see properties affected by User Information Privacy settings
- Does the calling user have permission to search for all the user roles they need to, in order find users in the result set

The users call operates on the root organization unit, so the permissions the calling user requires must be set on the organization org unit type.

By contrast, the Grades-related API calls operate not on the root organization unit, but typically on course offerings, sections, or groups. The permissions surrounding the calls there will get checked in the associated org unit types, so the calling user will need the right permissions against those types. Additionally, many of the calls related to course offerings (also sections and groups) require that the calling user be enrolled in the org unit in question (and in some cases, *explicitly* enrolled, not merely enrolled by cascading enrollment).

If you're sure that your calling user context does give you access to these things (and allows you access to this data through the web UI), and you still see a mismatch like this when you're calling through the API, then you may have uncovered a defect of some kind and you should please ask your organization's support contact, or your account manager, to open a support ticket to report that through Desire2Learn's [support desk](https://helpdesk.desire2learn.com/).

Comment: Well, I'm using a service account (It just has a role that was specifically created to serve admin and management purpose) that has the permissions to search for Student, Instructor, Tutors and many more. It has permissions to view User enrolments too. Most of the permissions are Organization level and Course Offering level. I have enabled all the UIPs. Moreover, I've done a cascading enrollment from Organization level.

What I'm unable to understand is that I'm still getting the 403 Not authorized for /d2l/api/lp/{version}/users/ with or without query parameter.

Comment: Your comments seem to differ from your original report: when you make this call, are you getting a 403 Not AUthorized response, or are you getting a 200 with zero returned items? The two are indicative of different issues. If you're getting a 403, then it would be very helpful to know -exactly- what your outgoing HTTP packet looks like, and exactly what your incoming HTTP response packet from it looks like.